# Cannot install Atom packages. npm ERR! code E500

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, atom-editor

I've just installed Atom and I wanted to install some packages. However, I couldn't do it due to this error:

Installing “script@3.32.2” failed.Hide output…

npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error - GET https://www.atom.io/api/packages/script/versions/3.32.2/tarball

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ronal.atom.apm_logs\2022-04-19T04_18_25_308Z-debug.log

I am not quite sure how to solve it. Have you guys had the same issue? It would be wonderful if you could help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Server is up. When using the following URL you'll get a response: https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-ternjs/versions/0.20.0/

When you add "tarball" to the end it errors.
Full URL: https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-ternjs/versions/0.20.0/tarball
Error: {"message":"Application error"}

I'm encountering the same issue with multiple other plugins too.

The Atom Github project has the issue registered, here is the link to the issue if you want to follow it: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/25417

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the GitHub repo link to download the package.

- For example you want to download `script` package.
- Visit their [main page](https://atom.io/packages/script), click on the [repo](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script) and get the link.
- For example https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script.git
- You don't need the whole link, just the main part which is `atom-community/atom-script`

Then open terminal (or command-prompt) and type the main-part:

```sh
apm install atom-community/atom-script
```

Thats how I installed it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case just go to the root folder in the error and delete the .apm directory (or folder) (`C:\Users\ronal.atom.apm_logs\2022-04-19T04_18_25_308Z-debug.log`)

It will clear the cache. Then close atom and open again and then if you install it will do. Just now tested this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).